# Question about Chains complexes

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have

$\mathcal{U}=\lbrace X-U, A\rbrace$ such that $\overline{U}\subset \overset{º}{A}$ and $X=\overset{º}{(X-U)}\cup \overset{º}{A}$ where $X$ is a topological space, $A$ is a subset of $X$ and $U\subset A$

Why $C_{\star}(\mathcal{U})=C_{\star}(X-U)+C_{\star}(A)$ ???

Please

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your definition of $C_*(\mathcal{U})$ but I think it means that any simplex must be in $A$ or $X-U$ due to restrictions on the diameter or because of barycentric division.

Comment: i dont understand, if i take an element of $C_*(\mathcal{U})$ we can take it $\sigma: \Delta_p\rightarrow \mathcal{U}= \lbrace X-U, A\rbrace$ how to continu please

Comment: Isnt the image of $\sigma$ in $X-U$ or in $A$ ?

Comment: yes, but why  we have $C_*(X-U)+C_*(A)$ ?

Comment: if i have that $\sigma\in C_*(X-U)+C_*(A)$ then it means that $\sigma=\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ where $\sigma_1\in C_*(X-U)$ and $\sigma_2\in C_*(A)$ so i think that it is right to say that $\sigma\in C_*(\mathcal{U})$ , but if the image of $\sigma$ is in $X-U$or in $A$ why we have $\sigma=\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ ?? thank you

Comment: Just one $\sigma:\Delta \rightarrow \mathcal{U}$ will be in either $C_*(X-U)$ or $C_*(A)$. A typical element of $C_*(\mathcal{U})$ is a sum of such simplices.

Comment: so authomaticaly $\sigma=\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ ?

Comment: It if say $\sigma \in C_*(X-U)$ then $\sigma=\sigma+0$

Comment: If the image of $\sigma$ is in $X-U$ this dont means that it isn't in $A$ so why 0 ?

Comment: The sum is not a direct sum.

Comment: i don't understand your message :
   
 
It if say σ∈C∗(X−U) then σ=σ+0